# Can't setup private network with systemd-networkd

Tags: private-network, systemd-networkd

I created two files in /etc/systemd/network/

- vbr0.netdev
- vbr0.network

Then I reloaded systemd-networkd, however interface vbr0 is DOWN

vbr0.netdev:

```
[NetDev]
Name=vbr0
Kind=bridge
```

vbr0.network:

```
[Match]
Name=vbr0

[Network]
DNS=8.8.8.8
Address=192.168.1.1/24
DHCPServer=yes
```

ip link show vbr0

```
5: vbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
link/ether d2:1a:32:c1:26:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global vbr0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::ffff:192.168.1.1/0 scope global tentative
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Status of systemd-networkd

```
systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2015-08-11 12:55:20 CEST; 19h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
 Main PID: 21937 (systemd-network)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
           └─21937 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

Aug 11 12:55:20 infra systemd-networkd[21937]: veth6cce540     : gained carrier
Aug 11 12:55:20 infra systemd-networkd[21937]: veth839e4d9     : gained carrier
Aug 11 12:55:20 infra systemd-networkd[21937]: veth5dacf8a     : gained carrier
Aug 11 12:55:20 infra systemd-networkd[21937]: vethd396754     : gained carrier
Aug 11 12:55:20 infra systemd-networkd[21937]: veth2ba9645     : gained carrier
Aug 11 12:55:20 infra systemd-networkd[21937]: docker0         : gained carrier
Aug 11 12:55:20 infra systemd-networkd[21937]: eth0            : gained carrier
Aug 11 12:55:20 infra systemd-networkd[21937]: lo              : gained carrier
Aug 11 12:55:20 infra systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Aug 11 12:55:20 infra systemd-networkd[21937]: vbr0            : link configured
```

systemd version - 215

What's wrong with my config?

Comment: Have you seen the status of your unit file? can you please paste the output for `systemctl status -l your-unit-file`?

Comment: @WitchDoctor updated my post

Comment: Why `DHCPServer=yes`? You need a static IP configuration?

Comment: @WitchDoctor I want to run simple dhcp server on this interface.
Even without this setting it does not work.

Comment: Try adding `[DHCPServer]` section as well.